# extracting portion of jar to a path

Tags: java, shell, jar, zip, aix

I am using the follwing command and my intention is to extract only DYEDistinctAppServer.topology from 
discovery1-full-8.1.0-07-10-2010_1055.jar  at data/product/template-topologies/DYEDistinctAppServer.topology path.

Command:

```
jar -xf discovery1-full-8.1.0-07-10-2010_1055.jar -C data/product/template-topologies/DYEDistinctAppServer.topology
```

Instead of extracting the files, it prompts me that I am using the command incorrectly and dumps out the help with all the various options.

Is there any syntax error as it is shown in the usage part.
I am using AIX OS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The option `-C` is to set the directory in which `jar` should run, not paths *in* the JAR file. Try:

```
jar -xf discovery1-full-8.1.0-07-10-2010_1055.jar data/product/template-topologies/DYEDistinctAppServer.topology
```